# How to catch stdout output from oozie spark jobs?

Tags: oozie, hue

Is it possible to catch the output information of a configured and started spark job via the oozie shell? Currently, i'm only able to catch the log information by using the shell command:

```
oozie job -log <job-ID> -oozie <oozie-server>
```

We implemented STDOUT and log4j messages within the spark job and we would like to see this messages over the oozie shell. But the spark job will be started via the Hue-Oozie workflow user interface and the shell should print out the log message like a job-tracker.

Comment: If you click on the little log icon on the Spark action on the single dashboard page of the job you should see the Spark job log from the Oozie launcher.

Comment: Ah thanks for that information. Is it possible to get the information of a running job over the shell?